# Vuex store is undefined in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a router and a global `beforeEach` hook to validate auth.

```js
import store from "@/store/store";

const router = new Router({
    // routes...
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.getAccessToken) { //undefined store
            next("/access/login");
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

And in my `store/store.js` file, I have an action that makes a request to validate user/password, and then tries to redirect to `/` route (protected route).

```js
import router from "@/router";

//state, getters...

actions: {
    login({commit}, authData) {
        // axios instance prototyped into vue $http object
        this._vm.$http.post("/auth/login", authData)
            .then(response => {
                commit("saveToken", response.data.token);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                commit("loginError", error.response.data);
            });
    }
},
mutations: {
    saveToken(state, token) {
        state.accessToken = token;

        router.push({
            path: "/"
        });
    },
    loginError(state, data) {
        return data.message;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the `store` in `router.js` is `undefined`. I have checked all imports, routes, and names several times, and they're fine.

Could it be a problem with the circular reference due to me importing `router` in the `store` and `store` in the `router`?

If that's the problem, how can I access the store from the router or the router from the store?

**EDIT**

I've tried to remove the router import from the store, and it works fine with the exception of:

```
router.push({
    path: "/"
});
```

because `router` is not imported.

**EDIT: ADDED @tony19 SOLUTION**

I've applied the solution that @tony19 provides and it works fine, but when I access the `/` route, `router.app.$store` is undefined.

The fixed code:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(`Routing from ${from.path} to ${to.path}`);

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!router.app.$store.getters["authentication/getAccessToken"]) {
            next("/access/login");
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

An image with the debugging session:

[image]

Comment: Just a silly question, are you sure you are exporting the store correctly? What happened when you removed the router reference in you store?

Comment: All works as expected, but can't make the ```router.push({ path: "/" });``` because router is not imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed caused by the circular reference. You could avoid importing the store in `router.js` by using [`router.app`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-app), which provides a reference the associated Vue instance the router was injected to. With that, you could get to the store by `router.app.$store`:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  /* ... */
  if (!router.app.$store.getters.getAccessToken) {
    next("/access/login");
  }
});
```

Comment: Removing the import it works but at that point ```$store``` is not defined: https://imgur.com/a/ZVKV5Hi. But just the first time that page loads.

Comment: Any solution with that ```undefined``` variable?