# Vue Router & Vuex : Getters are undefined on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to create a middleware according to the tickets present in the getters of a store

I first initialize Vuejs with a query to generate my state

**TicketStore.js**

```
const getters = {
    getTickets: state => state.tickets,
    getTicketById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.tickets.find(ticket => ticket.id === id)
    },

    //get nb of ticket for tabs
    nbTicket: state => state.tickets.length
};


const actions = { 

   .... ,

getTicketsFromAPI({commit}) {
        axios.get(api.get, {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.data.forEach(function (el) {

                    let dateFormat = require('dateformat')
                    let now = new Date(el.created_at)

                    commit('NEW_TICKET', {
                        id: el.id,
                        name: el.name,
                        msg: el.body,
                        date: dateFormat(now, "dd/mm/yyyy à H:MM:ss")
                    })
                })
            })
}
```

Init in **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import routes from './routes/router.js'
import App from './pages/layout/App'
import TicketStore from '@/store/TicketStore'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    created() {
        TicketStore.dispatch('getTicketsFromAPI')
    },
    render: h => h(App),
    router: routes,
}).$mount('#app')
```

This way works even if I do not think it's the most suitable

Now I want to stop the navigation if the ticket does not exist; so i created a middleware in my **routes.js**

I first tried :

```
    {
        path: '/ticket/:id', component: Ticket, name: 'ticket',

        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            const id = to.params.id
            const ticket = TicketStore.getters.getTicketById(id)
            /* eslint-disable no-console */
            console.log(id, ticket, to);
            /* eslint-enable no-console */
            if (ticket && ticket.id === id) {
                next()
            } else {
                next(false)
            }
        }
    },
```

This way works but if I reload the page, `const ticket` is not defined

So I searched ; I came across multiple discussions, never really helped me, like this one
[Vuex store is undefined in vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754891/vuex-store-is-undefined-in-vue-router/58603958#58603958)

I try this too

```
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            const id = parseInt(to.params.id)
            /* eslint-disable no-console */
            console.log(TicketStore.state)
            TicketStore.state.tickets.forEach(function (el) {
                if (el.id === id) {
                    next()
                } else {
                    next(false)
                }
            })
            /* eslint-enable no-console */
        }
```

Without success : this way doesnt work; but i have the ticket in my console on reload

My goal is to stop navigation if the ticket does not exist, even if the page has been reloaded

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should define `tickets` as an empty array by default in store.
Because for now it looks like you try get some data from store till it's not exist.